# Repeat For Loop if condition is not met

Tags: python, api

I am working on a bulk url shortener which uses the google shortener api. Since it has a limit on how much links you can create, it will create an error at some point.

If a Error is detected it should go back and to everything inside the for loop again, until it does work again. The problem is that when it detects an ERROR it just runs onward, which causes skipping of links which should be shorted. I marked the desired outcome with comments.

Only the if **name** == '**main**': part of the code is important but I provided my whole code to give it a context.

```
#!/usr/bin/python   

from sys import argv
import httplib2
import simplejson as json   

inputfile = argv[1]
outputfile = argv[2]    

API_KEY = "KEY" 

def shurl(longUrl):

        try: API_KEY
        except NameError:
                apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'    
        else:
                apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=%s' % API_KEY

        headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
        data = {"longUrl": longUrl}
        h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
        try:
                headers, response = h.request(apiUrl, "POST", json.dumps(data), headers)
                short_url = json.loads(response)['id']
                errorcode = 0
        except Exception, e:
            errorcode = 1   

        return (short_url, errorcode)   

if __name__ == '__main__':  

    infile = open(inputfile, "r")
    outfile = open(outputfile, "a+")    

    with infile as f:
            for line in f:
                # Go back to here
                longUrl = line
                outputS = shurl(longUrl)    

                shorturl = outputS[0]
                errorcode = outputS[1]  

                if errorcode == 0:  

                    print(shorturl)
                    outfile.write(shorturl + "\n")
                else:
                    print("ERROR, trying again.")
                    # Go back   


    outfile.close()
```

Comment: reset the errorcode in the first line of the `for` loop and put the rest of the contents in a `while` loop that checks for the `errorcode` being a success

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack-n-slash solution. I'd suggest rethinking your architecture if you have to do this

```
        for line in f:
            errorcode = 1
            while errorcode != 0:
                # Go back to here
                longUrl = line
                outputS = shurl(longUrl)    

                shorturl = outputS[0]
                errorcode = outputS[1]  

                if errorcode == 0:  
                    print(shorturl)
                    outfile.write(shorturl + "\n")
                else:
                    print("ERROR, trying again.")
                    # Go back
```

Comment: Did you meant errorcode = 0 and while errorcode != 1: ?

Comment: I don't think so. Or maybe I'm having a brain fart. you want the loop to repeat everytime the errorcode does not contain `0` which translates to success right? It might make more natural sense to name it `successcode` rather than `errorcode`.

Comment: Note that I am setting the errorcode to a default failure value right before the while loop (`1`)

Comment: It gives me following error after succefully creating 2504 links: NoTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 44, in <module>
    outputS = shurl(longUrl)
  File "3.py", line 30, in shurl
    return (short_url, errorcode)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'short_url' referenced before assignment

Comment: you have a bug in your `shurl`function. Please add the line `short_url = None` at the beginning of the function (right after the `def`). This is because unless the url shortening works it is not initialized. FYI this had nothing to do with the loops, which was your original question :)

Answer (score 0):

for loops in python always go forward, so it'd be better to use while loop in your case

e.g :

```
    with infile as f:
        while f:
            # Go back to here
            longUrl = f[0] 
            outputS = shurl(longUrl)    

            shorturl = outputS[0]
            errorcode = outputS[1]  

            if errorcode == 0:  

                print(shorturl)
                outfile.write(shorturl + "\n")
                f.pop(0)
            else:
                print("ERROR, trying again.")
                # Go back   


    outfile.close()
```